# hiding INC directories from cpan, so as to install ALL dependencies of a module in a directory

Tags: perl, cpan, perl-module

I come across requirements to package a perl module with all its dependent modules, for systems where one cannot run cpan install (internet connectivity issues on production). 
However, from the linux system i can do cpan install, already have these modules installed. Is there a way i can mask the @INC directories from cpan command, and provide just one directory to look for all perl modules, so that it downloads all dependencies into that local directory.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The majority of CPAN modules need to be built specially for the target platform, and building them elsewhere can cause problems. Are you dealing with Perl-only modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [lib::core::only](https://metacpan.org/module/lib%3a%3acore%3a%3aonly) and [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/module/local%3a%3alib) - the first excludes all non-core paths from @INC, the second makes it easy to set up a local perl module directory.

The combination should solve the problem.